# Why does a derived class call the base classes operator instead of its own operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-keyword

What shall I do in this example to trigger the right operator:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    virtual void operator/(A& a){cout << "class A";}
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    void operator/(B& b){cout << "class B";}
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new B;
    A* b = new B;
    *a / *b;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `"class A"` but it should be `"class B"`.
How can I solve this? Thanks.

EDIT: According to answers... should I do this for every derived class:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void operator/(A& a){cout << "class A";}
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void operator/(A& a) override {cout << "class B";}
};
class C : public B
{
public:
    virtual void operator/(A& a) override {cout << "class C";}
};
class D: public C
{
public:
    void operator/(A& a) override {cout << "class D";}
};
int main()
{
    A* a = new D;
    A* b = new D;
    *a / *b;
    //...
}
```

Comment: I think your proposed answer is still wrong. I think you should focus on clarifying the question. For example, you want to print 'class X', where X is the most-derived class which is compatible with *both* operands. Is this what you're trying to say?

Comment: @Aaron for example: Pointer to class A is pointer to class X(most derived) A* a = new X;  that's where I'm confused... means we have to everride all classes since pointer to class A could sometimes be a pointer to B in same porgram... A* a = new B;

Comment: Please, focus on clarifying your goal. Given *x / *y, do you wish to identify the most derived class which is compatible with both operands? Once you clarify your goal, we can all try to solve it.

Comment: To all concerned. I think we face three tasks. First: identify the ultimate *goal* here - defining (in plain English) the desired behaviour. Second: Explain why the code in the question fails to achieve the desired behaviour. Third: Write correct code.

Comment: My goal is very simple: "Is there other way to achive same thing in my edited question" in shorter way or more efficient way. thanks.    @Aaron I want to divide classes new D and new D whose pointers are pointing to class A (most base class)

Comment: the code you have written will always ignore the dynamic type of `b`. i.e. It will always choose the ` void operator/(A& ) `. So yes, the dynamic type of `a` will be relevant to selecting the particular function called, but the dynamic type of `b` will not be used.

Comment: (I mixed up my `a`s and `b`s in the last comment.) Anyway, your edited code doesn't do what you think it does, I think. @codekiddy, what output do you desire from the following examples: `A* x = new A; A* y = new C; *x / *y;`  and also `A* x = new C; A* y = new A; *x / *y;` and `A* x = new C; A* y = new C; *x / *y;`

Comment: The shorter way to get to same behaviour is to delete the methods for `operator/(B&);` and  `operator/(C&)` and `operator/(D&);` from your code. They will never be called and hence shouldn't be included. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(First, I'm going to try to explain what's happening at the moment, but at the end I'll try to write a 'correct' program.)

I'm going to use `x` and `y` instead of `a` and `b` - it's bit less confusing.

```
A* x = new C;
A* y = new B;
*x / *y;
```

The *static type* of `x` is `A` - i.e. that's what the type of the variable is. The *dynamic type*, the real type of the object pointed at by the variable, is `C`.

The *static type* of `y` is `A` - i.e. that's what the type of the variable is. The *dynamic type*, the real type of the object pointed at by the variable, is `B`.

So there are four types that seem to be involved here. But actually, the dynamic type of `y` is never relevant, as we will see. So that leaves (at most) three relevant types. To understand this, let's rewrite the expression as follows:

```
x -> operator/ (*y);
```

First, the compiler looks at the *static type* of `x`. In this case it is `A`. Then it looks for a method in the static type with the appropriate signature. What does 'appropriate signature' mean? The answer is that method lookup ignores the dynamic type of variables. The static type of `y` is A, and hence `operator/(A&)` is selected. (We know `y` is really a B, but that's ignored. )Finally, the runtime will look at the dynamic type of `x` (ignoring `y`). The dynamic type is `C`. Because the `operator/(A&)` was `virtual` in A, then the runtime will actually call the `C::operator/(A&)` instead.

In short, the dynamic type of `y` is not relevant. The methods `operator/(B&)` or `operator/(C&)` will never be called. Those methods should be deleted.

There's a fundamental asymmetry here. In `*y / *x`, the dynamic type of y would be relevant, but not the dynamic type of x.

#### How to fix it

Before 'fixing' the problem, we need to be sure we know what the question is. Hence, I'll clarify my interpretation first. If this is the wrong interpretation, apologies in advance.

I'm going to assume that the questioner intends that the *dynamic type* of `x` will always be the same as the *dynamic type* of `y`, and that if they are different then there should be an error message. For example, this code is expected to work:

```
A * x = new A;
A * y = new A;
*x / *y; // divide an instance of A by another instance of A
```

and

```
A * x = new B;
A * y = new B;
*x / *y; // divide an instance of B by another instance of B
```

and

```
A * x = new C;
A * y = new C;
*x / *y; // divide an instance of C by another instance of C
```

but **not**

```
A * x = new B;
A * y = new C;
*x / *y; // should give an error
```

or

```
A * x = new C;
A * y = new B;
*x / *y; // should give an error
```

Here is a complete program that does this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    virtual void operator/(A& z) {
            assert(typeid(z) == typeid(*this));
            cout << "class A" << endl;
    }
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void operator/(A& z) {
            assert(typeid(z) == typeid(*this));
            cout << "class B" << endl;
            B& b = dynamic_cast<B&>(z);
    }
};
class C : public B
{
public:
    virtual void operator/(A& z) {
            assert(typeid(z) == typeid(*this));
            cout << "class C" << endl;
            C& c = dynamic_cast<C&>(z);
    }
};
int main()
{
    A* x = new C;
    A* y = new C;
    *x / *y;
}
```

The operators in B and C do two things:

- test that the type of the second operand is as expected. i.e. confirm that both side of the `/` have the same type.
- cast the `A&` to the appropriate type, allowing the division code to have full access to both operands

Comment: thanks alot for explaining this, also thanks for comments which are also valuable! oh... tnx for edit too :D I see now

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons:

- `B::operator/(B&)` is **not** an override for `A::operator/(A&)`, so it will never get called in a polymorphic situation.
- `B::operator/` takes a `B&` as a parameter, but the static type of `*b` is `A`.

Comment: so in multiple inhertance of for example 5 classes I'll have to override each opearotr for each base and subbase class?

Comment: Only the first reason is relevant, really. The other operator won't even be considered for overload resolution because the static type of `*a` is `A`.

Comment: @Charles: I listed the second reason because the first problem could be "fixed" by adding a `virtual void A::operator/(B&)` function...

Comment: This is a good example of a very annoying limitation of the polymorphism in many languages, including C++ and Java. Ideally, it wouldn't just be polymorphic in the type of `this`. The version of `A::foo` that is inherited into `B` would ideally be of 'type' `operator/ (B& this, B& x);` rather than the current `operator/ (B& this, A& x);`. Other languages, such as Haskell (up to a point), have a more flexible idea of this.

Comment: @Aaron: You're talking about [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), right?

Comment: I'm not sure of the name of these things (I'm quite bad with jargon generally). So maybe that's what I'm talking about! I'm googling for that now :-)

Comment: hi, I've edited my qustion, can you explain the edit please :)

Comment: @codekiddy: The question is, what do you want those functions to do in real life?  What would their return type be?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I think what you suggest doesn't make sense on a fundamental level, as it breaks the entire OO design ("substitution principle" and "is-a" etc.) If anything you could have *contravariant* argument type overrides, which isn't allowed in C++, though.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth well return type could be any of derived class..., how will you know what's return type if you're deriving a class whose base class implementation you don't know for example.

Comment: @codekiddy: So you're saying that you'd want (for example), the result of `A a; C c; a/c` to be of type `C`?  That doesn't make sense though, because what if you did this: `A a; C c; A &ca = c; a / ca`.  The return type would now have to be of type `A`, which means you'd lose the `C` "part" of the result.  This is not really a limitation of C++; this is more fundamental than that.  Arithmetic is not really polymorphic...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth well that's complicated if you're writhing a library for other people.in that case you'll newer know would the other programer use polimorphism or not! in that case your lib is fail in general

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I'm not talking about changing the current behaviour in the language. I understand the whole "is-a" thing. I'm just thinking of cool new things that might, some day, be in the language that might simply a lot of the funky type magic I like from other languages. (That wiki article on double-dispatch is pretty cool, I'm learning a lot from it).

Comment: OK, I'm marking this answered since there is no way to call operators in polimorphism unless you override it in derived class. thanks alot to all

Answer (score 1):

The `B::operator/` is not an override for `A::operator/` because their parameters are different.

You can only override virtual functions (or operators) if their signatures are compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually override the `operator/` from `A`, since `B::operator/` has a different method signature then `A::operator/` (parameter is of type `B&` instead of `A&`). So your call of `operator/` on an object of type `A&` will call the only existing `operator/` for class `A`, which may be `virtual`, but isn't overriden in `class B`. Therefore what you need to do is change the `operator/` of `B` to

```
    void operator/(A& b){std::cout << "class B"<<std::endl;}
```

Note that `*b` couldn't be used as an argument for your `B::operator/` anyways, since it is of type `A&` and not of type `B&`.

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloading is resolved compile time using the static type and there's only one overload (the one in class A) that can handle an A (*b is an A to the compiler)